# npm install does not install any node modules in my React projects

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, npm-install, git-bash

When I run `npm install` it does not install any node modules in my React projects. When I tried to install react router it installed something, but nothing happened. It didn't show as being installed in either the json package or in node modules. I tried deleting the node modules folder to reinstall it, but installing with `npm install` didn't work anymore and nothing was installed. I created new projects, but it still didn't install anything. I tried to create a project with Vite because I was told that create react app is dead, so I made a project with Vite and it didn't install anything either. It says everything up to date, but it doesn't install anything.

I tried creating other projects and deleting node modules to reinstall, but now `npm install` is not working.

package.json of this project (dont work npm install in any prokect)

the console:

```
username@my-computer MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Pp/Portafolio a ver si funciona/portafolioch -mich (main)
$ npm install
up to date in 112ms
username@my-computer MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Portafolio a ver si funciona/portafolio-mich (main)
$ ls
index.html    public/  vite.config.js
package.json  src/
```

```
{
  "name": "portafolio-mich",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "description": "portafolio de Michelle con sus proyectos",
  "main": "index.html",
  "keywords": [
    "portafolio"
  ],
  "author": "Michelle",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Try to delete npm cache with this command: `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work npm install

Comment: try to create a new project inside C:\ without any extra folders and run react, I think the spaces you've added are causing the error "~/Desktop/Portafolio a ver si funciona"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which was fixed after a few hours.
I couldn't find a suitable solution until I tried my own.

**I managed to resolve it by downgrading my Node version from 16 to 14.15.0 using nvm (I'm using nvm).**

**So this is my solution - downgrade node version as above and try again.**

There are a few global solutions such as:
delete package-lock.json(windows):

```
del package-lock.json
```

delete node_modules(windows):

```
rmdir node_modules /s
```

'/s' will ensure deleting also child folders

if still not working try update your npm version:

```
npm i -g npm
```